# c++ if statements reading less than as an equal to

Tags: c++, if-statement, comparison

So TR[i] is an array which is set to 4 at the beginning of the code. Every verable is a float.

```
float = RA;
int i;
float TR[4] = { 4, 4, 4, 4 };

RA = 0.75f;
TR[i] = TR[i] - (RA + 0.25f);
// when you output TR[i] it is 3
if (TR[i] < 3)
{
    TR[i] = TR[i] - 0.25f;
}

cout << TR[i];
```

the output should be 3 but it's saying it is 2.5

My problem is that the program is still running the if statment when it should not be doing that because 3 < 3 is not correct? would love to know what is wrong?

Comment: This is just a fraction of my code if you need more information on the code let me know and I will share more. RA in my code is actually calculated out but to make it simple I just gave the number.

Comment: What's the value of `i`? You declare `int i` but never assign a value to it, at least not in the snippet you've shown.

Comment: @printf so i start off as 0 and when the program is run and the user wants to run it again then i++ happens

Comment: Please clarify it for future user, and edit your question to add an initialisation `i=0` somewhere. Or, even better, make it a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (you've already made the hardest part of the job of building a MRE)

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Besides, unless a compiler bug (and we all know that 99.99% of the "compiler error" are bugs in our code that we failed to see), I can't see under which cirumstances it could end up with 2.5. I would understand 2.75. That would be a classical case of "don't expect exact computation with floats" (tho, 0.25, 0.75, 1, 3, 4 are all exact values in FP32: 1×2⁻², 3×2⁻², 1×2⁰, 3×2⁰, 1×2²)

Comment: So, because of the errors I see in the attempt to produce an example (unitialized `i`, `float = RA` erroneous line, ...), I suspect that the error is in one of the part you did not reproduce here.

Comment: Generally speaking tho (but again, not sufficient to explain what we see here. Hence the reason I say that in comment, not in an answer), `==` is near meaningless with floats. And therefore so is the difference between `<=` and `<` (it is important to choose sometimes, particularly when we want mutually exclusive test. But yet, we can't assume what will be `<=` only and what will be both `<=` and `<` ; only that `<=` is the opposite of `>` and `<` the opposite of `>=`)

Comment: For example `if(0.3<0.2+0.1) cout <<"Inf"<<endl;` does print "inf". That is not an error (well, not a bug, at least. It is a normal, unavoidable, numerical error), What matter is not whether `0.3<0.2+0.1` or only `0.3<=0.2+0.1`. What matters is that since `0.3<0.2+0.1`, then `0.3>=0.2+0.1` is false. And indeed `if(0.3>=0.2+0.1) cout<<"Sup or eq";` prints nothing

Comment: Ok, thank you for that! I can provide more code that might show my mistakes or bugs in the code.